# Fetch data live every second from the database javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to fetch live data from the database but the setTimeout is not working, so if I submit data to the database it doesn't display them instantly in the blade(view) until I refresh the page. How can I display data without refreshing the page?

```
function getCount() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '{{route('
    live.review ')}}',
    success: function(data) {
        document.getElementById("mycount").innerHTML = getCount(3.6);

        function getCount(rating) {
            // Round to nearest half
            rating = Math.round(data * 2) / 2;
            let output = [];
            // Append all the filled whole stars
            for (var i = rating; i >= 1; i--)
                output.push('<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true" style="color: gold;"></i>&nbsp;');
             setTimeout(getCount, 1000);
            // If there is a half a star, append it
            if (i == .5) output.push('<i class="fa fa-star-half-o" aria-hidden="true" style="color: gold;"></i>&nbsp;');
             setTimeout(getCount, 1000);
            // Fill the empty stars
            for (let i = (5 - rating); i >= 1; i--)
                output.push('<i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true" style="color: gold;"></i>&nbsp;');
             setTimeout(getCount, 1000);
            return output.join('');
          }

        }
     });

 }
getCount();
```

Comment: Try ```setInterval```

Comment: setInterval is not working @Sajeeb Ahamed

Comment: You are calling the function just once. As the others have pointed out, an ajax call with setInterval() will do the deal

Comment: I changed `setTimeout(getCount, 1000);` to `setInterval(getCount, 1000);` and still not working or how do I put `setInterval` and where? @hans-könig

Comment: You are calling your function just once. Here getCount();

Comment: I understand now, perfect thanks that works `setInterval(getCount, 1000);`  @ hans-könig

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue here is that you're shadowing your outer `getCount` function with your inner `getCount` function, meaning that the `getCount` that is being passed as a callback to `setTimeout()` is the inner `getCount` that isn't actually preforming the needed ajax call and thus fetching the needed data.

To avoid the confusion that can be caused by shadowed variables it is considered best practice to avoid any variable shadowing through using unique values for all variables. I also removed some of the `setTimeouts` that were within the inner `getCount` function, because with them included, and actually calling the function you wanted them to be calling, you would be calling the ajax request multiple times at the end of the timeout, which doesn't make sense to me and I don't think that's what you meant to do.

I would, personally, re-write this block of code as follows:

```
const fetchCount = () => $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: '{{route('
  live.review ')}}',
  success: function (data) {
    // Round to nearest half
    rating = Math.round(data * 2) / 2;
    let output = [];
    // Append all the filled whole stars
    for (var i = rating; i >= 1; i--) {
      output.push(
        '<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true" style="color: gold;"></i>&nbsp;'
      );
    }
    // If there is a half a star, append it
    if (i == .5) {
      output.push(
        '<i class="fa fa-star-half-o" aria-hidden="true" style="color: gold;"></i>&nbsp;'
      );
    }
    // Fill the empty stars
    for (let i = (5 - rating); i >= 1; i--) {
      output.push(
        '<i class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true" style="color: gold;"></i>&nbsp;'
      );
    }

    document.getElementById("mycount").innerHTML = output.join('');

    setTimeout(fetchCount, 1000);
  }
});
fetchCount();
```

Essentially, what I did here is I entirely removed the second `getCount` function declaration since you are only ever using that function once, and you are using it internally. So all of that processing logic can just happen at the top of the function in order to prevent the weird hoisting that was going on previously.